# Erro ao tentar acessar Auth::user()->id, no laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

Erro:

```
Auth::user()->id trying to get a property of a non-object
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Scopes\Tenant\TenantScope;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Devedor extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [

        'nome',
        'endereco',
        'logradouro',
        'numero',
     //code

    ];
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        //$user = User::isAdmin();

        $usuario = User::findOrfail(Auth::user()->id); //Erro aqui

        $usuario->existePapel('Admin');

        if ($user) {
            echo "Usuario encontrado";
        }
        static::addGlobalScope(new TenantScope);
    }


}
```

Comment: `Auth::user()` tem alguma coisa aqui, e outra pergunta, você está logado?

Comment: Sim, estou logado, porém não está funcionando dentro da model

Comment: Eu to achando estranho, mas, da um `var_dump(Auth::user()) ` e verifique o que retorna, isso que você fez se estiver logado funciona ...

Comment: Obrigado Virgilio, mas já resolvi com a dica do Guilherme

Comment: Você resolveu aparentemente ... mas, quebrou o código, porque se isso não está funcionando quando o usuário teoricamente está logado (`Auth::user()->id`) o seu código tem problemas.

Comment: Outra coisa, se está fazendo isso no lugar errado, deveria ter ( `middleware`) para verificar isso, sendo que isso é feito na rotas

Comment: Sim, estou utilizando `Middleware` e isso é o mais estranho disso aqui não funcionar `Auth::user()->id`

Comment: olha não sei o que está fazendo, mas, se isso não funciona com o login com sucesso ta errado e outra coisa ai está no `model` não deveria ser ai ... bom só são alertas

Comment: Vou averiguar, o motivo ao certo. Muito Obrigado Virgilio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente esta rodando "deliberadamente" sem checar se o usuário esta logado, basta usar `Auth::check()`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

...


if (Auth::check()) {
    ... Aqui vai o seu código ...
}
```

Para pegar o id conforme a documentação seria:

```
$id = Auth::id();
```

Documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication

Comment: Obrigado man, era isso mesmo.